# Outer merge 2 dataframes - differ between left and right outer

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 `DataFrames` that present products. One is called `current` and the other `future`.

`current` represents the current state in the database
`future` represents a new state of the database

Let's say they have just 2 columns: 'id' and 'name'. I need to merge them and append a column which will have four values: `new`,`none`,`update` and `delete`.

`new` - this product is not in `current` dataframe

`none` - this product is in both dataframes and no value has changed

`update` - this product is in both dataframes but it has at least one different value

`delete` - this product is in `current` but it is not in `delete` dataframe

I want to use `outer` join because there are many products and `pandas` is very efficient in merging.

Example:

```
current = DataFrame(data=[
    [1,'a'],
    [2,'name'],
    [3,'c'],
],columns=['id','name'])

future = DataFrame(data=[
    [1,'a'],
    [2,'other_name'],
    [4,'c'],
],columns=['id','name'])

# DESIRED result after merging

 [1,'a','none']
 [2,'other_name','update']
 [3,'c','delete']
 [4,'c','new']
```

I tried this:

```
DataFrame.merge(current,future,how='outer',on='id')
   id name_x      name_y
0   1      a           a
1   2   name  other_name
2   3      c         NaN
3   4    NaN           c
```

Can you help me move? In real world, there are many columns, I can't just check if `name_x` is `None`...

Comment: how do you want to show the results for multiple columns? lets say you have 2 `_x` and 2 `_y` columns after merge and only 1 from each row matches, can you expand the example to 2-3 columns and expected output too?

Answer (score 2):

You can use numpy select to pass the conditions,

```
df = current.merge(future, 'outer', on = 'id')
condlist = [(df['name_x'] == df['name_y']), ((df['name_x'] != df['name_y'])&(df[['name_x','name_y']].notnull().all(1))), (df['name_x'].isnull()), (df['name_y'].isnull())]
choicelist = ['None', 'update', 'new', 'delete']
df['new'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist)


    id  name_x  name_y      new
0   1   a       a           None
1   2   name    other_name  update
2   3   c       NaN         delete
3   4   NaN     c           new
```

Comment: Thank you Vaishali, there is just one problem. What If I have many columns and I would like to not hardcoding the names?

Comment: Do you mean many name columns? As far as flag is concerned, if id is present in both dfs, the values will either match or not match (none or update) OR there would be NaN in wither _x or _y so I pretty much see 4 conditions here which are all covered

Comment: I mean many different columns like price, code, image, category, weight etc...

Comment: ah, then a more generic flag might be suitable. If you want named flags like you have asked for in the question, you can create condlist in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `indicator=True` in merge, it adds a new col `_merge` it tells you exactly what you're looking for, you can use that output to create the new column:

```
df = pd.merge(current,future,how='outer',on='id', indicator=True)
print(df)

   id name_x      name_y      _merge
0   1      a           a        both
1   2   name  other_name        both
2   3      c         NaN   left_only
3   4    NaN           c  right_only
```

Comment: Thank you, it's almost what I need, but is there a way to differ between first two rows? The second row has been updated and the first one not.

Comment: Considering there are many rows and I would like not to iterate over all columns.

Comment: Not sure you can avoid iterating, the condition to differentiate would be:
`df['_merge']=='both') & (df['name_x']==df['name_y']`